# Why do I get 'The directory '.' is not empty' using R Blogdown

Tags: html, r, blogdown

I'm developing a website using the `blogdown` library. https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html

When I try and load the theme with:

```r
library(blogdown)
blogdown::new_site(theme = 'https://github.com/pacollins/hugo-future-imperfect-slim.git')
```

I get the error and warning messages:

> Error: /Users/mrmole/Documents/R_Projects/my_blog already exists and
> is not empty Warning message: In blogdown::new_site(theme =
> "https://github.com/pacollins/hugo-future-imperfect-slim.git") : The
> directory '.' is not empty

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Note: I do not have another project named 'my_blog'.

Comment: You did not specify a directory where to save the new website, so it tries to store it in your current working directory. Use option `dir` to specify the directory of the new site.

Comment: Hi, okay thanks. I just used `dir = "Theme"` and that worked fine. What's the issue with it just saving to the directory I'm working in though? I like having the theme saved in a file better anyway as it's neater - I'm just interested

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to set a directory. This worked for me:

```r
library(blogdown)

new_site(dir = "Theme",
         theme = 'https://github.com/pacollins/hugo-future-imperfect-slim.git')
```